# Is there a way to not have to write `math.` before math functions in python?

Tags: python

It is very annoying and makes code harder to read to have to write `math.` before every math function in python. Is there an easy way to make it so we can write just the function name without `math.` before them?

Comment: what do you mean not write math. Are you asking if you can do math.sqrt() without math but just with sqrt()?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, i marked it as duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You use `from <module name> import *` to import all functions or variables within a module. In order to import one specific item, use `from <module name> import <to import>` In your case, you would use `from math import *`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from math import *
ceil(10.2)
# 11
```

As [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) suggested in the comments, this doesn't comply with the PEP 8 Style Guide, and I don't encourage you to use it. But I guess it can come in handy, especially if you 're using the interpreter.

Comment: *"Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided,…"* –PEP 8

Comment: I know, but it's what the user asked. Choosing to comply (or not) with PEP 8 is up to the user.

Comment: It would have been fine if you would have pointed that out in your answer.

Comment: Yes it would, so I made an edit but you commented first. Thanks for the suggestion. :D